# use rpm -V against backed-up database

Tags: database, backup, rpm, verify

rpm(1) provides a -V option to verify installed files against the installation database, which can be used to detect modified or missing files.
This might be used as a form of intrusion detection (or at least part of an audit). However, it is of course possible that the rpm database installed may be modified by a hacker to hide their tracks (see http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/rpm.php, last sentence)

It looks like it should be possible to back up the rpm database /var/lib/rpm after every install (to some external medium) and to use that during an audit using --dbpath. Such a backup would have to be updated fo course after every install or upgrade etc.

Is this feasible? Are there any resources that detail methods, pitfalls, suggestions  etc for this?

Comment: It certainly sounds feasible to me. Though this is going to be noisier than some other methods of tracking this information and I'm not sure it gains you much over other such fingerprinting tools/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes feasible. Use "rpm -Va --dbpath /some/where/else" to point to
some saved database directory.

Copy /var/lib/rpm/Packages to the saved /some/where/else directory,
and run "rpm --rebuilddb --dbpath /some/where/else" to regenerate
the indices.

Note that you can also verify files using the original packaging
like "rpm -Vp some*.rpm" which is often less hassle (and more
secure with RO offline media storing packages) than saving copies
of the installed /var/lib/rpm/Packages rpmdb.