# Is there an easy way to verify/compare installation against an RPM file?

Tags: security, rpm, integrity

I'd like to compare the contents of an RPM to an installed system (that professes to have the RPM already installed), looking for any files/directories that may have be different (or missing) -- something like [pkgchk on Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/pkgchk-1m.html).

It looks like `rpm -V` can be used to compare the system's filesystem(s) against the system's RPM database -- but I want to be able to compare an offline "golden" RPM with what's on the system (e.g., to avoid depending on a potentially tainted on-system RPM database or on incorrect version information from pre-release RPM files).

I know I could write something to unpack the RPM and then walk through the contents, comparing everything.  But is there any existing tool that can do the comparison in-situ?

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the "Similar Questions", I found [a reference to a way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29399360/318902), add the "-p" option to the command to yield: `rpm -Vp some*.rpm`.  I'd missed the aside on the man page saying that the query options were also applicable to the verification operation.

Comment: I feel weird answering my own question, especially when I should have figured it out from re-reading the man page.  But it took a bit of digging, so maybe this will help someone else (or me, when I need to do this check again)?

Comment: I like to consider myself an `rpm` expert, and I never even thought of trying that, so thanks for posting it!